# MySQL query to return the range of coordinates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in which there is a table called "coord". In the "coord" table there are fields such as latitude and longitude. The coord table has more than 5 million coordinates.

I need to filter out the latitude and longitude for certain range. I wrote the query to my best ability and came closest to below but it does not work.

```
SELECT latitude, abs(longitude)
FROM coord 
WHERE (latitude >=41.157530 and latitude <= 41.758601) 
AND   (longitude >= 124.379421 and latitude <= 124.961696) limit 10000;
```

I need it to be out put as following:

```
+----------+------------+
|Latitude  |  Longitude |
+----------+------------+
|41.153530 | 124.379421 |
|41.163530 | 124.382421 |
|41.165530 | 124.393421 |

Table should grow with those intervals and so on....
```

The range of coordinates I need are there... I just need to query the "coord" table and get the range of latitude and longitude and display ab table above.

If anyone of you know the better solution to make it work then it will be very helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: you specified `latitude` in the second part of your `and` conditional, instead of `longitude` twice

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
SELECT latitude, abs(longitude)
FROM coord 
WHERE (latitude >=41.157530 and latitude <= 41.758601) 
AND   (longitude >= 124.379421 and longitude <= 124.961696) 
Order By latitude limit 10000;
```

In AND condition please change latitude to longitude. And used order by clause.

Comment: If you're going to take someone elses comment, and turn it into an answer, at least post the explanation instead of just the modified query.

Comment: @pala_ thanks. But when I have posted the ans I don't find any comment, It may be due to slow internet connection. And I'm not at all interested in copying anyone's comments as an answer. Regards.

Comment: if the question was there, the comments were there